# problem with this module Image::OCR::Tesseract

Tags: perl, cpan, tesseract

I have activestate perl v5.8.8 installed i install the following module Image::OCR::Tesseract with the ppm

when I try to run the following code:

```
 use Image::OCR::Tesseract 'get_ocr';

 my $image = 'my_image.jp';

 my $text = get_ocr($image);
```

I get the below error messgae :

Invalid Parameter - -compress

1024 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Image/OCR/Tesseract.pm line 77.

Could someone help what could be this error message /or if someone have this problem beofre ?

Comment: Report this error to bug tracker: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Image-OCR-Tesseract

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the source of [`Image::OCR::Tesseract`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LEOCHARRE/Image-OCR-Tesseract-1.24/lib/Image/OCR/Tesseract.pm), this error is caused by `convert` not understanding the `-compress` parameter. Perhaps, you can try updating `ImageMagick` to a newer version.